# Speeding Up Angular DOM Creation

Tags: json, angularjs

So I am building a large menu out using a rather large JSON object. I originally tested it with about 250 nodes and the performance was fine. Since that was the scope for the project I wrote it off as completed and moved on.

Now the scope of the project requires there to be more than 3,000 nodes in the menu. In Chrome it takes about 3-4 seconds for the menu to be rendered, which is unacceptable enough. Then there's the fact that IE8 needs to be supported and takes almost a full minute to render the menu and you begin to see my problem.

Now normally I would build out a giant DOM string in JavaScript and apply it once it's done and it would take <1sec to build out the same DOM.  The problem is that all of the menu items have to be filtered based on checkboxes, which is why AngularJS was used in the first place, for real-time filtering of menu items (not to mention easy rendering with recursive includes) which lowered initial development time.

So now I am stuck with trying to find a way to get Angular to create thousands of nodes quickly that are still data-bound so they can be filtered. I'm already using a custom function to hide/show the nodes instead of having them be built out every time which made the menu blazing fast when adding/removing filters. Now I just need to find a way to get over this initial rendering hump.

Here is the markup for the menu itself:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu_item_renderer.html">
<div class="menu-item">
    <a ng-show="category.link" href="{{category.link}}" class="menu-item-title" target="{{category.target}}">
        {{category.title}}
    </a>
    <span ng-show="!category.link" class="menu-item-title">
        {{category.title}}
    </span>
    <span class="menu-toggle-btn" ng-show="category.categories" data-ng-class="childrenFiltered(category.categories)"><i class="icon-plus" /></span>
    <span class="menu-item-border" ng-show="!category.categories"></span>
</div>
<ul class="menu-category-list list-unstyled">
    <li data-ng-repeat="category in category.categories" data-ng-class="filterResults(category)" data-ng-include="'menu_item_renderer.html'" class="menu-category"></li>
</ul>
```

The JSON object is huge, but I've set up a JSFiddle for you all so you can take a look at the render times.  Note that the JSON object is in an NG-INIT due to the implementation restrictions of the application. This is how it is in my actual application, which is why I've included it in the same manner here. I'm aware that putting a massive JSON object in the markup is bad, there just isn't a way around it on this project.

http://jsfiddle.net/cy2SW/

Is there a method/technique I can use here to speed up the initial display of the menu?

Comment: Are you familiar with lazy loading?

Comment: Can you just bring down the root nodes and then make a call to get the child nodes when a user clicks on a parent node?  2 way binding of 1000's of objects is going to give you a performance headache.

Comment: I am familiar with lazy loading, it's not an option for this implementation. They want the full menu in one request, no extra HTTP requests allowed/permitted. This is for a tool their sales people have to use in the field and will largely be used on mobile devices (phones/tablets), which makes this load time problem even worse. Because of the mobile important they want the whole thing to load once and be available from the first load.

Comment: You could look at some of the ng-repeat alternatives, even if they do not solve your problem outright, perhaps they use techniques that could work for you. One is http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=1 and another (mine, but the use case is more limited) https://andytompkins.github.io/angular-template-repeat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I think could resolve your performance problem is to only construct your DOM when your user needs it. You can add a button next to your category combined to a `ng-if` property on your children list.

I've made a little example of how you can integrate this inside your existing application : http://jsfiddle.net/cy2SW/1/.

With this method, the DOM creation time is drastically reduced.